# How to run Gradle from a Python3 script

Tags: python, python-3.x, gradle

I want to run Gradle from a Python3 script. I can call Gradle from a terminal, but I can not figure out how to call it from a Python script.

example for call in terminal:

```
path gradle test --tests *SomeTest.someSpecificFeature*
```

Comment: Take a look at [`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.system).

Answer (score 1):

I believe that's the correct way for running shell commands.

```
import subprocess
process = subprocess.Popen('path gradle test --tests *SomeTest.someSpecificFeature*', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
    import os
    os.system('path gradle test --tests *SomeTest.someSpecificFeature*')
```

You can invoke any shell command in such a manner.

See https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/os.html#os.system

Answer (score 0):

This is how I run gradle in Python

```
import subprocess
res = subprocess.check_output('./gradlew -q getVersionName', shell=True)
```

To parse the result output

```
print(res.decode("utf-8"))
```

An example output will be

```
initialize  Gradle Environment .....
initialize  Gradle Environment completes...
3.0.0
```